# How to summarise event types with defined hierarchy per day and week (Use SQL or ETL)

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, etl

If I have the following events table and I want to summarise it so that for each ID, EventDay,EventWeek I get 1 row such as EventStatus is reported as the most severe/concerning `(High>Low>Normal)`. The solution would need to cope with more event weeks and event days

> Is that something that can be accomplished with example MySQL or MariaDB compatible SQL or
>   would ETL processes be better suited to the task (with outline of steps)?

**SampleTable**

```
ID  EventStatus EventDay    EventWeek
1   Normal      1           1
1   Low         2           1
1   High        2           1
1   Normal      2           1
2   Normal      1           1
2   Normal      2           1
3   Normal      2           1
3   Low         2           1
```

**Desired Output**

```
ID  EventStatus EventDay    EventWeek
1   Normal      1           1
1   High        2           1
2   Normal      1           1
2   Normal      2           1
3   Low         2           1
```

Would the solution cope with additional columns to constrain the events (EventLocation) in addition to EventDay and EventWeek

Comment: Do you know how many rows your table is and the amount it is likely to grow by? Creating a VIEW in MySQL would work if your data is relatively small.

Comment: At the moment its 20,0000 rows and I would expect it to increase by only a few hundred rows each update

Comment: This is a trivial task for SQL. (At least as far as MySQL is concerned) creating a VIEW affords no benefit here.

Comment: Care to provide some pointers on the SQL needed?

Comment: I guess, but that's not the question that was asked.

Comment: Updated the question to ask for example SQL or ETL steps which would solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

Here's one idea. An index on (id,eventweek,eventday) would help. If you could store the priority (H,L,N) as intergers (e.g. 3,2,1 respectively) then you could add this to the index too, which would further enhance performance - although there's probably other ways too...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(ID  INT NOT NULL
,EventStatus VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,EventDay INT NOT NULL
,EventWeek INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(ID,EventWeek,EventDay,EventStatus)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,'Normal',1,1),
(1,'Low',2,1),
(1,'High',2,1),
(1,'Normal',2,1),
(2,'Normal',1,1),
(2,'Normal',2,1),
(3,'Normal',2,1),
(3,'Low',2,1);

SELECT a.* 
  FROM my_table a
  JOIN
     (
       SELECT id
            , MAX(CASE eventstatus WHEN 'High' THEN 3 WHEN 'Low' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END) eventstatus
            , eventday
            , eventweek 
         FROM my_table 
        GROUP 
           BY id
            , eventweek
            , eventday
     ) b
    ON b.id = a.id 
   AND b.eventstatus = CASE a.eventstatus WHEN 'High' THEN 3 WHEN 'Low' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END
   AND b.eventweek = a.eventweek 
   AND b.eventday = a.eventday;

+----+-------------+----------+-----------+
| ID | EventStatus | EventDay | EventWeek |
+----+-------------+----------+-----------+
|  1 | Normal      |        1 |         1 |
|  1 | High        |        2 |         1 |
|  2 | Normal      |        1 |         1 |
|  2 | Normal      |        2 |         1 |
|  3 | Low         |        2 |         1 |
+----+-------------+----------+-----------+
```

Comment: Nice solution using `CASE` and `MAX` I end up with the eventstatus integer value instead of the text value. Any ideas what error I'm making?

Comment: @mobcdi If you're copying the code above, then no. No idea.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the need for the 2nd case statement `AND b.eventstatus = CASE a.eventstatus WHEN 'High' THEN 3 WHEN 'Low' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END` could you explain the code. Doesn't the sub query get you the result if you use `SELECT id
            , MAX(CASE eventstatus WHEN 'High' THEN 3 WHEN 'Low' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END) ,eventstatus
            , eventday
            , eventweek 
         FROM my_table 
        GROUP 
           BY id
            , eventweek
            , eventday `

Comment: No. The subquery returns the integer. The super query matches the integer back up with the corresponding status - otherwise (I can assure you) I wouldn't have bothered writing it.

Comment: A really useful trick for understanding how any aggregating query works, is just to leave off the aggregation - so remove, MAX() and replace GROUP BY with ORDER BY